# how to fetch value from JSON object?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

I want to delete data from the table and database using multiple select. but  it only deletes the first row selected. I also use the Firebug to fetch the req.body.id for the WHERE condition of my sql query, and it gives this POST request:

id  139,138
oper    del

It only delete the row with the Id number 139.

heres my query:

connection.query("DELETE FROM "+content.table+" WHERE ?",content.condition,function(err,result){

```
content.condition= {id:req.body.id};
```

so the actual query became like this:

```
"DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE id = 139,138"
```

Sorry for my poor english, but I hope someone could help me! 
any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The proper syntax for WHERE is `WHERE ID IN (id1, id2, ..., idn)`

Comment: Thanks Akshat Jiwan Sharma, I never thought of that "IN" operator :) now my problem is SOLVED! thank you! :)

Comment: I posted it as an answer then.

Comment: Well + 1 for Nicolas I just edited your post :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper syntax for WHERE is `WHERE ID IN (id1, id2, ..., idn)`